# how to move data from Salesforce to SQL Server

Tags: apex, api

I've done some checking on tools to move data from Salesforce to a SQL Server database such as DBAmp, Jitterbit, Informatica Cloud, etc.

Are there any options to reliably communicate with an outside data source in near real time without buying additional products using Salesforce? Pros and cons?

Thanks.

Comment: For a very simple case you could probably create something using triggers and web service APIs. The product solutions are built for the general case of many objects with many field types and complex relationships (including e.g. object self references). And they (hopefully) have large tests suites to make sure they work and they (hopefully) get updated 3 times a year when the platform updates. So buying can be good value for money.

Comment: In a simple case where you create an account, the trigger fires on insert and then invokes an external web service passing in the data to be inserted/updated in sql server?